# Using Elm to create a JavaScript library. How do I instantiate?

Tags: elm

Let me start by saying I'm new to Elm. My interest is using it to author JavaScript libraries. What I'm trying to understand is how to instantiate a new object, or similar, from an end-user perspective.

In JavaScript I might use: `var my_lib = new MyLibrary();`

In Elm, I would need to do `var my_lib = Elm.MyLibrary.worker();`

I don't want to require the end user to do it the Elm way. I want it to behave like vanilla JavaScript.

I should add I'm using a Gulp workflow, so perhaps the answer can come from that perspective. I'm not finding any.

Comment: If you're looking to call Elm code _from_ javascript, then `.worker()` is probably your best option. That will give you access to ports through the `update` function through commands and subscriptions. Unfortunately, Elm does not (yet) expose functions to javascript in a standardized and future-proof way (you could always hack together something since it emits javascript after all, but it wouldn't be guaranteed to be backwards compatible)

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. That's pretty much what I assumed. I appreciate the sanity check. ;-)

Answer (score 1):

That depends on what you mean with "behave like vanilla JavaScript". If `Promise` is vanilla javascript you could simply wrap the Elm interface in your own function:

```
function myModuleName (maybeSomeArgs) {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    var app = Elm.MyLibrary.worker(maybeSomeArgs);
    app.ports.out.subscribe(resolve);
    app.ports.error.subscribe(reject);
  });
}
```

And the end-user would just use it like:

```
myModuleName(42).then(doSomething);
```

This of course assumes you have adapted your Elm script to be used in this way. If you have multiple functions you want to expose you need to handle that in your ports. If you have just one function and prefer dirtier js in exchange for cleaner Elm you could do something like:

```
function myModuleName (maybeSomeArgs) {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    var node = document.createElement("div");
    var app = Elm.MyLibrary.embed(node, maybeSomeArgs);

    setTimeout(() => {
      resolve(node.innerText);
    }, 0);
  });
}
```

If your Elm app's main is something like `main = text "some result"`.

To package this for an end-user you could just put this is a file and
`cat elm.js > dist.js && cat interfaceCode.js >> dist.js`. I'm sure that
Gulp has a more complicated way of doing it though.